# What happens when a process ready to execute but out of the CPU receives a signal?

Tags: cpu, process, signal, queue

I know pretty well what happens when it is running and when is blocked, but the behaviour when the process is in the ready queue is something unknown for me. Thank you for the time.

Comment: Not sure if I parsed "out of the CPU correctly". Are you asking what happens when a process is ready to run, but not running and it receives a signal?

Comment: Exactly that´s what I´m asking about, sorry for the poor question. I have 3 books of operating system at home but I only find information about blocked and running processes, but not about ready-to-run processes.

Comment: I would **guess** that the process stays 'READY to run' than it would process the signal when it gets CPU time (read, when the task scheduler moves it to RUNNING). But this may vary per OS and it has been ages since I did anything with operating systems other than installing or cloning them. It will be interesting to see which answers people post.

Comment: So, the process may have the same behaviour as when it is blocked or undefined? More or less I mean.

Comment: @alberto define "undefined" :)

Comment: I´m talking about the "guess" used in the last comment. The process ready-to-run will stay the same if it has not arrived to the execution state and it receives a signal?